# Microsoft graph: forward email to group without forwarding it to members and guests

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm [forwarding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-forward?view=graph-rest-1.0) emails from outlook inbox using Microsoft graph API, but when i forward the email the email is also forwarded to all the owners,members and guest that are in the group.

Is there any option to avoid this behavior and forward the email only to the group inbox either by sending some parameters or by changing some settings on the group itself?

Comment: Could you post an example of what you're seeing? Is it adding each member of the group to the `To` property?

Comment: No it's only adding the email address of the group itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. If a user decides to subscribe to Group, they see emails to that Group in their inbox. This isn't something you can control, it's entirely up to the user if they would prefer it to surface in their inbox or not.